# streamplot over a pseudocolor plot from polar to cartesian coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, polar-coordinates, cartesian-coordinates

I have a polar (r,theta) grid (i.e. each cell is an annulus sector) and 2-dimensional arrays of physical variables with values defined in such a grid: a scalar field (density) and a vector field (b = (br,btheta)).
I'd like to plot the two fields into the same plot with cartesian coordinates. In particular: I need the pseudocolor plot of the scalar field with the streamplot of the vector field over that in a cartesian grid.
This is my code:

```
## first_step: density plot 
## from polar to cartesian coordinates
##  
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.figure()
R,Theta = np.meshgrid(r,theta)
x = R*np.sin(Theta)
y = R*np.cos(Theta)
plt.pcolormesh(x,y,density.transpose())
##
## second step: overplot the streamplot of a vector field 
## form polar to cartesian coordinates
## 
x,y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
r = np.sqrt(x*x+y*y)
th = np.arctan2(x,y)
s = np.sin(th)
c = np.cos(th)
bx = br*s+bth*c
by = br*c-bth*s
plt.streamplot(x,y,bx,by)
```

The pseudocolor plot of the density works well. Some issues happen when trying to overplot the streamlines of the vector field. In particular, the second step would work well only if a cartesian grid were built at the beginning and independently of the polar grid, like:

```
x = np.linspace(x_beg,x_end,Nx)
y = np.linspace(y_beg, y_end,Ny)
x,y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
```

But since I have a polar grid, I can only built the cartesian grid after using the np.meshgrid of polar coordinates. It is this passage that seems to give me some issues with the vector field.

Thanks for any suggestions!